# Using jQuery to show/hide divs based on the content of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a jQuery UI date picker that calculates the number of days selected. The default value is 1. I would like to display a different div depending on the number of days selected.

```
<div class="dates">1</day>

<div class="one-day" style="display:block;">You are staying for one day</div>

<div class="more-than-one-day" style="display:none;">You are staying for more than one day</div>
```

If the value of .dates changes to > 1, what method can I use to hide .one-day and show .more-than-one-day?

Like this:

```
<div class="dates">2</day>

<div class="one-day" style="display:none;">You are staying for one day</div>

<div class="more-than-one-day" style="display:block;">You are staying for more than one day</div>
```

Hope you can help!

M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated to include new requirements.

You could try using something like this:

```
var datesFunction = function () {
    var numDays = $('.dates').html();
    if (numDays == 1) {
        $('.more-than-one-day').hide();
        $('.one-day').show();
    } else if (numDays > 1) {
        $('.one-day').hide();
        $('.more-than-one-day').show();
    } else {
        //Default, maybe hide both?
        $('.one-day').hide();
        $('.more-than-one-day').hide();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    var dateDiff = function(selectedDate) {
          var fromDate = $('#from-date').datepicker('getDate');
          var toDate = $('#to-date').datepicker('getDate');
          var dateDifference = 0;
          if (fromDate && toDate) {
                dateDifference = Math.floor((toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / 86400000);
          }
          $('.dates').text(dateDifference);
          datesFunction();
    };

    $('#from-date').datepicker({ 
        onSelect: dateDiff
    });
    $('#to-date').datepicker({
        onSelect: dateDiff
    });
});
```

[Example JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SmNhH/3/)

Comment: Hey that works well but if the user then changes the date range will the divs update too?

Comment: Sure I'll update the fiddle and update my answer, pretty much you just need to hook into the onSelect event of the datepicker as outlined by skparwal

Answer (score 0):

just try this one:

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
      here is your hide and 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dates">1</div>
<div class="dates">2</div>

<div class="one-day" style="display:block;">You are staying for one day</div>    
<div class="more-than-one-day" style="display:none;">You are staying for more than one day</div>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.dates').click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
    if($(this).html()=='1')
    {

        $('.one-day').show();
        $('.more-than-one-day').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.one-day').hide();
        $('.more-than-one-day').show();
    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c2xmG/)